# Does WP "out-of-the-box" allow user profile photos?

Tags: profiles

How does a user upload a photo to their profile? Do you need a plug-in to do that? Right now the user has a gray box with a white silhouette headshot.

Answer (score 0):

By default wordpress gets a picture from [gravatar](http://gravatar.org) based on the email associated with the profile. If you would like to be able to upload your own pictures through the administration you will need to use a plugin such as [Easy Author Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-author-image/) or similar.